# iOS Charts(Daniel Gindi) - when doing UILongPressGesture func chartValueSelected is not being invoked

Tags: ios, swift, charts

While doing UIPanGestureRecognizer or UITapGestureRecognizer the chartValueSelected is invoked.
In case i am doing UILongPressGestureRecognizer nothing happens.

```
  extension GraphTableViewCell: ChartViewDelegate {
    func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    marker.color = ColorName.reddishPink
    lineChart.data = viewModel.updateGraph(with: Int(entry.x))
 }
}
```

The method above invokes on UIPanGestureRecognizer or UITapGestureRecognizer yet on UILongPressGestureRecognizer nothing happens.
Is there a way of workaround this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much research i see that in the pod they dont handle UILongPressGestureRecognizer so i forked it and asked for pr